# Scroll view in android does not scroll image

Tags: android, scrollview

I am creating Scroll grid view an Image view in android, only my Grid view was scrolling but my image was not scrolling.

How to scroll my image when I am scroll my Grid View?

Here is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView 

        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80sp"
        android:src="@drawable/fddf"


        />


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@+id/image"
          android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

        android:numColumns="2" />






     </RelativeLayout>>
     </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First of all remove scrollview enclosing, gridview is not required

Comment: can u tell me correct way ,I want scroll my grid view along with Image View @war_Hero

Comment: how to increse my gridview col space